# How To Close Excel and Workbook (C#)?

Tags: c#, excel, project

My goal is to read an excel file, make some modifications, and then save the workbook. I have the code working for generating the file, but it seems that the file then gets locked for editing/read only mode after the second iteration when I'm using the existing file. Please take a look. Thanks! The error is prompted from where I am trying to delete the initial file after saving it to a temporary file.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
    _Workbook oWB;
    _Worksheet oSheet;
    _Worksheet TrackingSheet;

    try
    {
        //Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (track == false)
        {
            //oXL.Visible = true;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            //Unique ID Tab
            TrackingSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            TrackingSheet.Name = "UniqueID Tracking List";
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                TrackingSheet.Cells[i+1, 1] = listBox1.Items[i];
                UIDList.add(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }

            TrackingSheet = oWB.Worksheets.Add();
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "SlackTrend";


            //Add table headers going cell by cell.

            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Status Date";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Unique ID";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Task Name";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "% Complete";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Finish Date";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Baseline Finish";
            //Creates the monthly bins (User entry for range) - goes from current month onward if creating
            int monthS = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;  
            int yearS = comboBox3.SelectedIndex + 2000;
            Date status = CurrentFile.ProjectProperties.StatusDate;
            int yearstatus = status.getYear();
            int monthstatus = status.getMonth();
            int daystatus = status.getDate();
            System.String statusDate = (monthstatus + 1) + "/" + daystatus + "/" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String statuskeyCode = (monthstatus + 1) + "-" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String monthYear = monthS + "-" + yearS;
            int slackLocation = 6; //Double Check this logic
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {

                oSheet.Cells[2, 6 + i] = monthYear;
                monthS++;
                if (monthS > 12)
                {
                    monthS = 1;
                    yearS++;
                }
                if (monthYear.Equals(statuskeyCode))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 6 + i] = statusDate;
                    slackLocation = 6 + i;
                }
                monthYear = monthS + "-" + yearS;

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < UIDList.size(); i++)
            {
                net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf((Int32.Parse(UIDList.get(i).ToString()))));
                Duration d = c.Duration;
                System.String name = c.Name;
                //Date Conversion
                Date d1 = c.Finish;
                Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                int year = d1.getYear();
                int month = d1.getMonth();
                int day = d1.getDate();
                int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 1] = UIDList.get(i);
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 2] = name;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 3] = percent;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 4] = newDate;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 5] = newBaselineDate;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, slackLocation] = slack;
                oSheet.Cells[1, slackLocation] = statusDate;

            }
            //Expands columns
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "Z1");
            aRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
            oWB.SaveAs(name4);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            //oWB.Close(true, name4, null);
            //oXL.Quit();
            //Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
            //of Microsoft Excel's lifetime.
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;

        }
        else
        {
            //else statement for existing tracking file
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            xlWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(name3,0,false);
            //Selects active sheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetFocus = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
            xlWorkSheetFocus.Activate();
            //Collecting UIDs to trend (Assuming no added/deleted)
            ArrayList UIDList = new ArrayList();
            /*
            for (int i = 1; i < xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                UIDList.add(xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString());
            }
            */
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[i + 1, 1] = listBox1.Items[i];
                UIDList.add(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }
            //Trending new data points for existing UIDs
            xlWorkSheetFocus = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xlWorkSheetFocus.Activate();
            //user-inputted status month bin
            int monthS = comboBox2.SelectedIndex+1;
            int yearS = comboBox3.SelectedIndex+2000;
            Date status = CurrentFile.ProjectProperties.StatusDate;
            int yearstatus = status.getYear();
            int monthstatus = status.getMonth();
            int daystatus = status.getDate();
            System.String statusDate = (monthstatus + 1) + "/" + daystatus + "/" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String statuskeyCode = (monthstatus + 1) + "-" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String monthYear = monthS + "/1/" + yearS + " 12:00:00 AM";
            //Create List for Tracking File Comparison
            ArrayList existingList = new ArrayList();
            //Making List to check if UID already exists
            for(int i = 3; i < xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1; i++)
            {
                existingList.add(xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString());
            }
            // loop through UID List
            for (int j = 0; j < UIDList.size(); j++)
            {
                if (existingList.contains(UIDList.get(j).ToString()) == false)
                {
                    System.String UID = (System.String)UIDList.get(j);
                    net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(UID));
                    Duration d = c.Duration;
                    System.String name = c.Name;
                    //Date Conversion
                    Date d1 = c.Finish;
                    Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                    Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                    int year = d1.getYear();
                    int month = d1.getMonth();
                    int day = d1.getDate();
                    int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                    int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                    int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                    double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                    System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                    System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                    //updating existing data from latest IMS
                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1] = UID;
                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2] = name;
                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3] = percent;
                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4] = newDate;
                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5] = newBaselineDate;
                    for (int z = 0; z < xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 6; z++)
                    {
                        if (monthYear.Equals(xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[2, 6 + z].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 6 + z] = slack;
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[1, 6 + z] = statusDate;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //loop through trend sheet list
                else
                {
                    for (int k = 3; k < xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1; k++)
                    {
                        //check to see if list UIDs match
                        if (UIDList.get(j).ToString().Equals(xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 1].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            // Collect latest task data -> CORRECT THIS COMPARE
                            System.String UID = (System.String)UIDList.get(j);
                            net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(UID));
                            Duration d = c.Duration;
                            System.String name = c.Name;
                            //Date Conversion
                            Date d1 = c.Finish;
                            Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                            Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                            int year = d1.getYear();
                            int month = d1.getMonth();
                            int day = d1.getDate();
                            int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                            int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                            int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                            double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                            System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                            System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                            //updating existing data from latest IMS
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 2] = name;
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 3] = percent;
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 4] = newDate;
                            xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 5] = newBaselineDate;

                            for (int z = 0; z < xlWorkSheetFocus.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 6; z++)
                            {

                                if (monthYear.Equals(xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[2, 6 + z].Value.ToString()))
                                {
                                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[k, 6 + z] = slack;
                                    xlWorkSheetFocus.Cells[1, 6 + z] = statusDate;

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = xlWorkSheetFocus.get_Range("A1", "Z1");
            aRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\acdavis1\\Desktop\\temp.xlsx");
            //xlWorkBook.SaveAs(name3);
            //File.Delete("C:\\Users\\acdavis1\\Desktop\\temp.xlsx");
            //xlWorkBook.Save(); // cant open read only
            xlWorkBook.Close(0);       
            oXL.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
            File.Delete(name3);
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;


        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception theException)
    {
        System.String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = "Error: ";
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't that because the workbook you created at first step is still opened so you get readonly access when you try again?

Comment: The funny thing is it works perfectly fine the first time. I can open and close to the file afterwards with no problem, and it's not read-only. But when I use an existing file, I do call xlworkbook.close() and oxl.quit(), which is the excel application, I also notice my excel is still going on the processes in my task manager, not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Excel.exe is in your task manager because you are not properly releasing COM object - I had to solve same issue just yesterday. Here is really good thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1  Could be also related to your readonly issue

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments! Is there a quick way to check all of the releases I need to make? I know that there's a GC.Collect() method, but I don't see any output from calling it. Please clarify if you know, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should **NEVER** use two dots (call a method or a property of a property of an object) in COM objects (like in `oXL.Workbooks.Add`) **AND** you should properly release **ALL** the COM objects created (you **only** release `oXL`) even if something goes wrong (try adding a finally clause to `your try` - catch releasing all the objects)

(**Note**: I'm not on my computer at the time, try it and comment if needed):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application oXL = null;
    Excel.Workbooks oWBs = null;
    Excel.Workbook oWB = null;
    Excel.Worksheets oSheets = null;
    Excel.Worksheet oSheet = null;
    Excel.Worksheet TrackingSheet = null;
    Excel.Range aRange = null;
    Excel.Range oSheetCells = null;
    Excel.Range oSheetColumns = null;
    try
    {
        //Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (track == false)
        {
            //oXL.Visible = true;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWBs = oXL.Workbooks;
            oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oWBs.Add(Missing.Value);
            //Unique ID Tab
            TrackingSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            TrackingSheet.Name = "UniqueID Tracking List";
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                TrackingSheet.Cells[i+1, 1] = listBox1.Items[i];
                UIDList.add(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }

            TrackingSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWBs.Add();
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "SlackTrend";


            //Add table headers going cell by cell.

            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Status Date";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Unique ID";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Task Name";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "% Complete";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Finish Date";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Baseline Finish";
            //Creates the monthly bins (User entry for range) - goes from current month onward if creating
            int monthS = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;  
            int yearS = comboBox3.SelectedIndex + 2000;
            Date status = CurrentFile.ProjectProperties.StatusDate;
            int yearstatus = status.getYear();
            int monthstatus = status.getMonth();
            int daystatus = status.getDate();
            System.String statusDate = (monthstatus + 1) + "/" + daystatus + "/" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String statuskeyCode = (monthstatus + 1) + "-" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String monthYear = monthS + "-" + yearS;
            int slackLocation = 6; //Double Check this logic
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {

                oSheet.Cells[2, 6 + i] = monthYear;
                monthS++;
                if (monthS > 12)
                {
                    monthS = 1;
                    yearS++;
                }
                if (monthYear.Equals(statuskeyCode))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 6 + i] = statusDate;
                    slackLocation = 6 + i;
                }
                monthYear = monthS + "-" + yearS;

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < UIDList.size(); i++)
            {
                net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf((Int32.Parse(UIDList.get(i).ToString()))));
                Duration d = c.Duration;
                System.String name = c.Name;
                //Date Conversion
                Date d1 = c.Finish;
                Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                int year = d1.getYear();
                int month = d1.getMonth();
                int day = d1.getDate();
                int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 1] = UIDList.get(i);
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 2] = name;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 3] = percent;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 4] = newDate;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, 5] = newBaselineDate;
                oSheet.Cells[i + 3, slackLocation] = slack;
                oSheet.Cells[1, slackLocation] = statusDate;

            }
            //Expands columns
            aRange = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "Z1");
            aRange = aRange.EntireColumn;
            aRange.AutoFit();
            oWB.SaveAs(name4);
            //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            //oWB.Close(true, name4, null);
            //oXL.Quit();
            //Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
            //of Microsoft Excel's lifetime.
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;

        }
        else
        {
            //else statement for existing tracking file
            oWBs = oXL.Workbooks;
            oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oWBs.Open(name3,0,false);
            //Selects active sheet
            oSheets = oWB.Worksheets;
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oSheets.get_Item(2);
            oSheet.Activate();
            aRange = oSheet.UsedRange;
            aRange = aRange.Rows;
            oSheetCells = oSheet.Cells;
            //Collecting UIDs to trend (Assuming no added/deleted)
            ArrayList UIDList = new ArrayList();
            /*
            for (int i = 1; i < aRange.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                object value = oSheetCells[i, 1].Value;
                UIDList.add(value.ToString());
            }
            */
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                oSheetCells[i + 1, 1] = listBox1.Items[i];
                UIDList.add(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }
            //Trending new data points for existing UIDs
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oSheets.get_Item(1);
            oSheet.Activate();
            //user-inputted status month bin
            int monthS = comboBox2.SelectedIndex+1;
            int yearS = comboBox3.SelectedIndex+2000;
            Date status = CurrentFile.ProjectProperties.StatusDate;
            int yearstatus = status.getYear();
            int monthstatus = status.getMonth();
            int daystatus = status.getDate();
            System.String statusDate = (monthstatus + 1) + "/" + daystatus + "/" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String statuskeyCode = (monthstatus + 1) + "-" + (yearstatus + 1900);
            System.String monthYear = monthS + "/1/" + yearS + " 12:00:00 AM";
            //Create List for Tracking File Comparison
            ArrayList existingList = new ArrayList();
            //Making List to check if UID already exists
            for(int i = 3; i < aRange.Count+1; i++)
            {
                object value = oSheetCells[i, 1].Value;
                existingList.add(value.ToString());
            }
            // loop through UID List
            for (int j = 0; j < UIDList.size(); j++)
            {
                if (existingList.contains(UIDList.get(j).ToString()) == false)
                {
                    System.String UID = (System.String)UIDList.get(j);
                    net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(UID));
                    Duration d = c.Duration;
                    System.String name = c.Name;
                    //Date Conversion
                    Date d1 = c.Finish;
                    Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                    Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                    int year = d1.getYear();
                    int month = d1.getMonth();
                    int day = d1.getDate();
                    int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                    int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                    int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                    double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                    System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                    System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                    //updating existing data from latest IMS
                    oSheetCells[aRange.Count + 1, 1] = UID;
                    oSheetCells[aRange.Count, 2] = name;
                    oSheetCells[aRange.Count, 3] = percent;
                    oSheetCells[aRange.Count, 4] = newDate;
                    oSheetCells[aRange.Count, 5] = newBaselineDate;
                    oSheetColumns = oSheet.UsedRange;
                    oSheetColumns = oSheetColumns.Columns;
                    for (int z = 0; z < oSheetColumns.Count - 6; z++)
                    {
                        object value = oSheetCells[2, 6 + z].Value;
                        if (monthYear.Equals(value.ToString()))
                        {
                            oSheetCells[aRange.Count, 6 + z] = slack;
                            oSheetCells[1, 6 + z] = statusDate;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //loop through trend sheet list
                else
                {
                    for (int k = 3; k < aRange.Count + 1; k++)
                    {
                        //check to see if list UIDs match
                        object value = oSheetCells[k, 1].Value;
                        if (UIDList.get(j).ToString().Equals(value.ToString()))
                        {
                            // Collect latest task data -> CORRECT THIS COMPARE
                            System.String UID = (System.String)UIDList.get(j);
                            net.sf.mpxj.Task c = CurrentFile.GetTaskByUniqueID(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(UID));
                            Duration d = c.Duration;
                            System.String name = c.Name;
                            //Date Conversion
                            Date d1 = c.Finish;
                            Number percent = c.PercentageComplete;
                            Date Baseline = c.BaselineFinish;
                            int year = d1.getYear();
                            int month = d1.getMonth();
                            int day = d1.getDate();
                            int yearb = Baseline.getYear();
                            int monthb = Baseline.getMonth();
                            int dayb = Baseline.getDate();
                            double slack = c.TotalSlack.Duration;
                            System.String newDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                            System.String newBaselineDate = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + (year + 1900);
                            //updating existing data from latest IMS
                            oSheetCells[k, 2] = name;
                            oSheetCells[k, 3] = percent;
                            oSheetCells[k, 4] = newDate;
                            oSheetCells[k, 5] = newBaselineDate;
                            oSheetColumns = oSheet.UsedRange;
                            oSheetColumns = oSheetColumns.Columns;
                            for (int z = 0; z < oSheetColumns.Count - 6; z++)
                            {
                                object value = oSheetCells[2, 6 + z].Value;
                                if (monthYear.Equals(value.ToString()))
                                {
                                    oSheetCells[k, 6 + z] = slack;
                                    oSheetCells[1, 6 + z] = statusDate;

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            aRange = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "Z1");
            aRange = aRange.EntireColumn;
            aRange.AutoFit();
            //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            oWB.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\acdavis1\\Desktop\\temp.xlsx");
            //xlWorkBook.SaveAs(name3);
            //File.Delete("C:\\Users\\acdavis1\\Desktop\\temp.xlsx");
            //xlWorkBook.Save(); // cant open read only
            oWB.Close(0);
            File.Delete(name3);
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;


        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception theException)
    {
        System.String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = "Error: ";
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
        errorMessage = System.String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oXL != null) oXL.Quit();
        /* release the newest first */
        ReleaseCOM(oSheetColumns);
        ReleaseCOM(oSheetCells);
        ReleaseCOM(aRange);
        ReleaseCOM(TrackingSheet);
        ReleaseCOM(oSheet);
        ReleaseCOM(oSheets);
        ReleaseCOM(oWB);
        ReleaseCOM(oWBs);
        ReleaseCOM(oXL);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
}

private void ReleaseCOM(object com)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(com);
        com = null;
    }
    catch
    {
        com = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! May I ask - will the 2 dots (which I intend to fix) cause the issue alone? In other words, if I release everything properly, would this cause my program to crash still or is it just a best practice? Ideally, I'd like to have my program be functional first. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the two dots: No, it will not solve the issue alone, you need to a) not use two dots and b) release everything. The finally clause will make sure that even if your program crashes at some point, the COM objects are still released.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll modify my code accordingly and let you know how it works!

Comment: In the "Finally Statement" i'm getting an error message for the (oXL != null) conditional. The message is "Use of unassigned local variable 'oXL'.

Comment: I also noticed you replaced my listbox with arange.count, I don't think this would work because i'm reading to/from an object in my UI and my excel tracking file spreadsheet.

Comment: @AndreDavis Done (set them to null), for your other comment, just declare new ranges before the `try` where all the other Excel variables are! (and release them in the `finally` clause)

Comment: Ok, those answers make a lot of sense! Thanks for your answers I'll start playing with my code now. I'll let you know if it works/breaks and provide updated code.

Comment: Sure, let me know if I can help you further with this!

Comment: Thanks, starting to work on the updates now. Just notice u declared the new variables to avoid 2 dots with workbooks instead of workbook, which my program doesn't seem to recognize - is this a typo? Should they both be _Workbook and same for sheet and sheets?

Comment: I'm getting issues with this line: TrackingSheet = oWBs.Add();
It won't let me convert from workbook to worksheet, should I use the oWB and make a new variable for oWB.worksheets; and then do TrackingSheet = variable.add();?

Comment: oWB.worksheets doesn't work actually. Not sure what to do. Does it make sense to make a new variable: Sheets TrackingSheets = null; and TrackingSheets = oWB.Worksheets; TrackingSheet = TrackingSheets.add()?

Comment: Sorry, did you tried casting the result as a `Worksheet`? `TrackingSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWBs.Add();`

Comment: Got it, thanks anyways though! I do have another question though, can I use 2 dots for "listBox1.Items.Count"? Is listbox1 a COM object? I know listbox1.items is an arraylist.

Comment: Yeah, the only 2 dots problem is for the COM objects (i.e. `Excel.*` in your case), everything else, work it as usual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173167/discussion-between-ivan-garcia-topete-and-andre-davis).